# Install Angular Material Error Package install failed, see above

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to Install Angular Material using **ng add @angular/material** but I get those errors I am up to date with my angular cli
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYMa1.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the right version of angular material for your version of angular. You are trying to install Angular material v13, so you probably have some Angular version lower than 13.

For example if your Angular is v12:

> npm install @angular/material@12.2.13

Or update your angular application to 13 following the [Official Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) and then install angular material.

*If you read the error, it is telling you that it can't find certain packages, for example @angular/core@13. So if you check your `package.json`, you will find that your @angular/core does not match what the installation is looking for.*

Another option is to force the installation, and then update your angular application. Whichever way you go, the versions need to match.

Comment: Angular CLI: 13.2.6
  -Node: 16.15.0 So I checked my angular version using ng --version and it said I am angular 13

Comment: Those are your global versions, what about those in the project? Check the `package.json` in the project.

Comment: even in package.json it's 13.2.0

Comment: Ah yh, sorry, the error says it could not resolve dependency core@13.3.11. You need to install those dependencies. The error is pretty descriptive. It is saying you have 13.2, but need 13.3.11 or higher... The same for animations. You should be good just by updating your angular.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, consider marking it as the right answer. Cheers.

Comment: nah I tried updating my angular but sill have the same problem

Comment: I think the problem in the project it self cause I tried to add the angular materials to new project and it worked normally

Comment: You could try to delete the lock-file (`package-lock.json` or `yarn-lock` depending on your package manager). Update the version numbers in the `package.json` and `yarn install`.